# Exclude elements while validating a Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend Form with a subform which only is shown when the user selects a specific checkbox. 
Some of the fields in the subform are required IF the checkbox is selected, otherwise, the fields in that subform should be ignored by IsValid.

What would be the way to go here?

Comment: You could use a custom validator on the dependent elements. The whole data set is passed to each validator as $context and can be used if you have to validate based on other values.